# vbscript start a process

Tags: process, vbscript

I have a vb script that starts an exe (or even a process without gui):

```
strCom = "Start calc"  
WSHShell.Run(strCom)
```

It doesn't start the program, when I open task manager I can't see it.
But when I write the command "Start calc" directly in the command line it opens it.

How can I do it using the script?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`start` is built-in to `cmd.exe`; it's not an actual program.

[`WSHShell.Run`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d5fk67ky%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) takes a physical file , not a `cmd` built-in.

Therefore, you can write `WSHShell.Run("calc.exe")`

Comment: Good answer, but I just want to note that `WSHShell` needs to be initialised first. Here's an example using Internet Explorer: `CreateObject("WScript.Shell").Run("iexplore")`

Answer (score 4):

1. Starting a system process like calc.exe or cmd.exe

   **code**

   ```
       Dim shl  
       Set shl = CreateObject("Wscript.Shell")  
       Call shl.Run("""calc.exe""")  
       Set shl = Nothing  
       WScript.Quit
   ```
2. Starting a normal process

   **code**

   ```
      Dim shl  
      Set shl = CreateObject("Wscript.Shell")  
      Call shl.Run("""D:\testvbs\someServices.exe""")  
      Set shl = Nothing    
      WScript.Quit
   ```
3. You can launch any batch file too using VBscript.
   just provide the path of batch file in shl.run() while calling it.

Comment: Worked with windows 11. Cool :)

Answer (score 2):

Or/In addition - if using `start` is important:

```
CreateObject("WScript.Shell").Run "%comspec% /c start /wait notepad.exe", 0, True

CreateObject("WScript.Shell").Exec "%comspec% /c start E:\Handapparat\Algorithms\diktaat.pdf"
```

resp. some variations thereof.

Answer (score 1):

```
CreateObject("WScript.Shell").Run("**Application**")
```

I don't plan on making video for this script in action.
Though I did make a cool error game with it.