# How to run VSCode from the command prompt

Tags: windows, cmd, visual-studio-code, admin, runas

I for security reasons cannot run VSCode plainly. I have opened it in the past, but now due to specific reasons, I may only run VSCode from the command prompt. I've tried

`start "path/to/file" code` and `start code "path/to/file"`
but none work I'm on `Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.17134.407]`

how may I run this by going to <kbd>Windows</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd> then 'cmd' then start/ run?

Also it would be great if I could use this for a separate user.

I'm looking for something like:
`Runas /user:user\admin /savecred "C:\Program Files (x86)\vs-code.exe"`

Comment: P.S. I didn't install the code directive command while I was inside VSCode before the issue arised

Comment: https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/command-line

Answer (score -3, accepted):

> Well shoot, as it turns out that after doing some experimentation I found out that there's a way. Do this:

1. Simply stick this:

   ```
   runas /user:Techtiger255\admin /savecred "C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code\Code.exe"
   ```

   inside of a shortcut (`.lnk file`)

2. Open your command line of choice (`Powershell` or `Cmd`) and enter the exact file path of your shortcut ex: 
   `"C:\Users\Standard\Desktop/VSCODE.lnk"` and hit go, stupidly simple really, just had to find the code.exe file path.

Comment: This is not how .lnk files work. You can't just edit their contents like a file, as they are a symlink, not a file. The only way this could possibly work is because (possibly) when you run the .lnk file with that command inside it, from within Powershell, powershell is executing the contents as a command. That means you can't double click it

Answer (score 0):

The use of start is useless if VSCode is in the environment variables.

You can use `code C:\Users\%username%\Desktop\File.c` for exemple.If it doesn't work, I advise you to use a [vbs script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7866231/vbscript-start-a-process) instead

*You also don't need to run VSCode as an administrator unless you need to edit a file in a protected folder.*

Answer (score 0):

Maybe not the exact answer to the question, but...

To start Visual-Studio-Code from CMD into the current folder write:

```
code %cd%
```

The environment variable cd tell VS-Code to open it with the current folder

Answer (score 0):

just open a cmd terminal and type code followed by return keyborad key.

Answer (score -1):

Just open a cmd terminal and type code followed by a `.`

Comment: just open a cmd terminal, go to your working directory  and type code followed by a point : `code .`